# Semantic-UI: How to use custom icons in multiple dropdown remote search?

Tags: drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create a searchable multiple dropdown with custom icons that fetches its data from a remote source.

Basically, a mix between [this](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#tagging-and-user-additions), [this](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#remote-content) and [this](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#multiple-search-selection).

Take [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emzero/aavt7o6k/1/) for example: What I want to is a way to modify the dropdown items (not the labels when they are selected, but the actual items in the dropdown list). SUI provides `onAdd` and `onLabelCreate` callbacks but those are only useful when an item has already been selected.

Is there a callback that allows me to modify the generated menu items?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a bit old, but since I was looking to do something similar and the answer provided have some issues, when you click on the arrow or inside the search box the icons disappears or duplicate, I found a workaround similar to the solution posted but I used the onResponse event instead of onShow, I hope this could be useful for someone else looking to do the same.

```js
$('#sourcesSearch').dropdown({
  saveRemoteData: false,
  apiSettings: {
url: 'https://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EJYceWRub',
cache: false,
onResponse: function(response) {
  // make some adjustments to response
  $.each(response.results, function(index, item) {
    if (item.value.indexOf('user') >= 0) {
      response.results[index].name = "<i class='user icon'></i>" + item.name;
    } else if (item.value.indexOf('group') >= 0) {
      response.results[index].name = "<i class='users icon'></i>" + item.name;
    }
  });
  //console.log(response);
  return response;
},
  },
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="sourcesSearch" class="ui multiple fluid search selection dropdown">
  <input name="sources" type="hidden" />
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Sources...</div>
  <div class="menu">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#sourcesSearch').dropdown({
  saveRemoteData: false,
 apiSettings: {
   url: '//beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EJYceWRub',
    cache: false
  },
  onShow : function(){
   $(this).children('.menu').children('.item').each(function(a, b){
     var user_group_identifier = $(this).attr('data-value');
        if(user_group_identifier.indexOf('user') >= 0){
         $(this).prepend("<i class='user icon'></i>");
        }else if(user_group_identifier.indexOf('group') >= 0){
         $(this).prepend("<i class='users icon'></i>");
        }
    });
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="sourcesSearch" class="ui multiple big fluid search selection dropdown">
  <input name="sources" type="hidden" />
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Sources...</div>
  <div class="menu">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about custom class names coming with the API results? For example  `<i class='users icon_group_somename'></i>`. What's the way to get access to the response data in 'onShow'?