# Change dropdown menu items format using results from API - Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, dom, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

Currently setting up a dropdown which gathers results from an API. I have set it up as follows:

```
$("#my-dropdown").dropdown({
    minCharacters: 2,
    apiSettings: {
        cache: false,
        url: getCorrectUrl(),
        method: 'POST',
        onResponse: function(users) {
            var response = {
                success: true,
                results: []
            };
            $.each(users, function(index, item) {
                response.results.push({
                    name: item.name,
                    value: item.id
                });
            });
            return response;
        }
    }
});
```

And it is returning the correct data, just not in the form that I want. I would like to **format the menu items how I want**.

Specifically, what I'm currently getting is:

[image: Simple format dropdown menu items]

...but what I want is:

[image: Custom formatted dropdown menu items]

I have seen the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798655/semantic-ui-how-to-use-custom-icons-in-multiple-dropdown-remote-search), which uses the `onShow` function to change the items into a custom form, but is manual manipulation of the DOM the only way to do it? Or is there a built in method to specify custom format menu items for use in a API-powered dropdown menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before, it involves defining a custom type of a template for generating the HTML for the results from the response.

I would go to `dropdown.js` in your `Semantic/components` directory and find:

```
$.fn.dropdown.settings.templates = { //line 3715 in version 2.2
```

you will find some predefined templates there for how the JSON is used to generate the results.

I didn't edit the code there, instead I copied the usual results template (`templates.dropdown`), tweaked the copied contained js to fit my results and created my own function from it in my own js file:

```
function addDropdownTemplate(name){
    $.fn.dropdown.settings.templates[name] = function (response) {//use response
    //use the edited version of the default template here    
}
}
```

When you call the above function, you will add your own template for converting the response to the HTML results, to use it just specify the type of template you will use in the api settings:

```
apiSettings: {
   //your other settings as in the question above
   type: 'imageResult' //imageResult is an example, you can call it whatever 
   //you like as long as it's the same as what you passed
   //to your function as the name parameter
   }
```

I am looking at my code and I didn't even attach an `onResponse` event in the `apiSettings`, wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I came accross that post and tried to apply the best answer solution, but failed to make it work. 
However, it led me to discover another way to achieve what you want to do, using the "onSuccess" callback under "apiSettings":

```js
$('.player-dropdown.remote').dropdown({
  on: 'click',
  direction: 'downward',
        allowAdditions: false,
        allowReselection: true,
        fireOnInit: false,
        apiSettings: {
            url: 'search?q={query}',
            onSuccess: function(response) {
             var html   = '' ;
             $('.player-member-menu').empty();
       $.each(response.results, function(index, item) {
         html += '<span class="select-player nowrap item " data-value="' + item.value + '">' 
         + '<small class="description right-floated">' + item.description + '</small>'
         + '<span class="text">' + item.name + '</span>' 
         + '</span>';
       });
       $(this).find('.player-member-menu').html(html) ;
      },
        },
        minCharacters : 3,
        searchDelay: 500,
        duration: 500,
        saveRemoteData: false,
        filterRemoteData: false,
        showOnFocus: true,
        fullTextSearch: true,
    });
```

In my example, the results array is formatted as asked in the docs, excepted that each item has 3 parameters instead of 2: name, value and description.